# .NET Delete in ListView isn't passing any values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

For some reason, all my ListView functions work, except my delete button. I have debugged, and it points to the right method for deletion, but it's just passing all null values. I have no idea what the issue is, everything else seems to be working just fine. here is my listview code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="EntReqListView" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" DataSourceID="EntranceReqODS" Visible="false">
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="MarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CourseNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"/>
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ProgramIDTextBox" runat="server" value="<%# ProgramID.Text %>" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID")%>' onkeydown="javascript:return false"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="EntReqCourses" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="CourseListODS"
                        DataTextField="SubjectName"
                        DataValueField="CourseID"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="MarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">
                            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr runat="server" style="">
                                    <th runat="server"></th>
                                    <th runat="server">ProgramID</th>
                                    <th runat="server">CourseID</th>
                                    <th runat="server">CourseName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">Mark</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server" style="">
                            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                </Fields>
                            </asp:DataPager>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="MarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

I set up all my CRUD methods through the wizard, here is the delete method it goes to:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, false)]
    public void EntReq_Delete(EntranceRequirementInfo item)
    {
        using (Pathway_Model context = new Pathway_Model())
        {
            EntranceRequirement existing = context.EntranceRequirements.Find(item.CourseID, item.ProgramID);
            context.EntranceRequirements.Remove(existing);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My ODS:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="EntranceReqODS" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Pathway_System.Entities.DTOs.EntranceRequirementInfo" DeleteMethod="EntReq_Delete" InsertMethod="EntReq_Add" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="EntReqList_byID" TypeName="Pathway_System.BLL.PathwaysController" UpdateMethod="EntReq_Update">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CertificateList" Name="programID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you also post your C# code for the deletion and source code for DataSource control EntranceReqODS?

Comment: There is no c# code on the code behind for that page, because uses the auto generated functions in the wizard when you select create update and delete. I will post my ODS's though

Comment: I guess it isn't really an ODS but they just point to methods in my controller class, I've posted the delete controller it points to.

Comment: I don't understand, is this WebForms or MVC? Your ListView code is WebForms code and you are saying EntReq_Delete() function is a Controller. This is confusing me.

Comment: Your ListView has DataSourceID="EntranceReqODS" which means there should be some asp.net code for EntranceReqODS same as ListView. Can you post that? I want to see how your ODS calls EntReq_Delete() function?

Comment: Sorry, it is a web form MVC. I have a system separate from my website, which has a controller class, EntReq_Delete() is a method within the controller

Comment: Yes, I will post this!

Comment: Do you have any Primary key in your EntranceRequirements table like ID or EntranceRequirementID? Or just composite key of Course ID and ProgramID?

Comment: I found a problem in your code. Delete controller usually requires ID as a parameter and not a whole class or object. You then use that ID to find the object from your dbcontext and then remove it. You need to make change at two places. Change your controller method to accept CourceID and ProgramID as parameters and add DeleteParameters in your ODS.

Comment: they are a composite key.

Comment: I found a problem in your code. Delete controller usually requires ID as a parameter and not a whole class or object. You then use that ID to find the object from your dbcontext and then remove it. You need to make change at two places. Change your controller method to accept CourceID and ProgramID as parameters and add DeleteParameters in your ODS.

Comment: I tried passing just values but it's expecting an object, can't I just pass the object, like all my other methods, and extract the fields from the object like I've done everywhere else?

Comment: Have you also changed your EntReq_Delete method in your BLL for example, public void EntReq_Delete(int CourseID, int ProgramID) { ... } ?

Comment: You didn't provide the attributte DataKeyNames to your ListView, thats the WHY!

Comment: Yes. tried that, but since I am dealing with an object of type EntranceRequirementInfo, it is always passing this object. I have done this on numerous other projects (passing objects for CRUD function) without any issues, I don't know why this one is being picky with me.

Comment: I never use datakeynames for listviews, and has worked before, aren't they only for gridviews?

Comment: Have a look at this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.deleteparameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yeah...thats not the problem.